# Get ApiDescription.Documentation from console app

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on a console app that auto generates documentation from a Web Api project, similar to the MVC Help pages. The data is retrieved from the Web API MVC help pages. I.e.:

```
var documentationProvider = Configuration.Services.GetDocumentationProvider();
var apiModelDescriptions = new ApiModelDescriptions(Configuration);
```

In my console app, looping through the controllers and the actions, System.Web.Http.Description.ApiDescription.Documentation is null. But when running from Web Api, it is populated with the XML Summary comments (///Comment before a method).

I also noticed that when I try to leverage config.Services.GetDocumentationProvider, it is null. Is it related? Can I leverage this from a console app? It works from Web Api.

From console app:

```
HttpConfiguration config;
config = new HttpConfiguration();            
WebApiConfig.ConfigRoutes(config);
var documentationProvider = config.Services.GetDocumentationProvider();
```

From the Web Api help pages:

```
    public HelpController()
        : this(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration) { }

    public HelpController(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        Configuration = config;
    }

    public HttpConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var documentationProvider = Configuration.Services.GetDocumentationProvider();
        var descriptions = config.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions;
```

**I do not want to parse the XML generated by the assembly.**

Comment: I suggest checking out the ApiExplorer service

Comment: I should have included ApiExplorer in my code snippet. I have looked at it without any luck yet